# Incompatibilidade de Caracteres no Sass ( 'IBM437' e 'UTF-8')

Tags: css, sass

Meu problema ocorre quando tento usar o `--watch`da seguinte forma:

```
--watch estilos.scss:estilos.css
```

Meu objetivo é realizar a compilação automática no momento em que salvo o arquivo.
O erro que aparece no prompt de comando é o seguinte:

```
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM437 and UTF-8
Use --trace for backtrace.`
```

Uso Windows 7 e a instalação do Ruby está ok.

Comment: Já tentei utilizar:

`@charset 'UTF-8';`

no início do arquivo sem nenhum espaço antes e não funcionou.

Comment: veja se você está salvando os arquivos como utf8

Comment: Como faço para verificar isso @Caio ?

Comment: o sublime text, por exemplo, tem uma opção chamada "save with encoding". Veja se o seu editor não tem algo parecido

Comment: Eu uso Sublime. Tentei essa opção e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: você tem algum import nesse `estilos.scss` ?

Comment: Não @Caio , nenhum import. Li em algum lugar que poderia ser por conta do uso de acentos em comentários, então removi todos os comentários e continuou com o mesmo problema...